# Container internal communication

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run a full-stack application using the docker-compose file. However, back-end(SpringBoot) and front-end(ReactJs) containers can not communicate with each other using the service name.

I know that containers can communicate in user-defined bridge networks.   my back-end connects to the database using db:5432 address. 
  However, when I try to make a get request from frontend to the back-end:
example: http://back-end:5055/getLogs?page=0

It is not working -> net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

So, Frontend couldn't make any requests to the backend.

If I expose ports from back-end and use http://localhost:5055/getLogs?page=0 everything works fine.
 However, I want to expose only front-end port to the user and the other stuff (back-end/DB) I want it to be isolated.

How to set up communication between these two???

docker-compose file

```
services:
  db:
    ... env vars
    networks:
      - my-net
  back-end:
    image: back/preproduction:0.0.1
    networks:
      - my-net
  front-end:
    image: front/preproduction:0.0.1
    ports:
      - "80:3055"
    networks:
      - my-net

... volumes

networks:
  my-net:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: without exposing the Backed you won't be able to request, so you have to expose it.

Comment: @Avi That's not true. Exposing just makes docker service available to docker host. In the network created by docker-compose, container can communicate directly with the service name. For the questioner, what is your `docker-compose` file version?

Comment: @leopal I'm using version '3'

Comment: @Avi, I didn't expose db, however back-end has no problems conntecting to it. There seems to be another issue

Comment: @РамазанСаатов If you do not have any particular reason to use bridge driver, consider removing all network related stuff from docker-compose file and try again. Also make sure that everywhere you are accessing your services with the docker specified names.

Comment: @leopal oh.. might be I am wrong, I will look into it

Comment: The React app ultimately runs in a browser, not inside a container, and so it can't use these Docker-internal hostnames.

Comment: User defined networks have an embedded DNS server : :https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/ . I know it deprecated but you could try with using `--link`.                      
 Containers for the linked service are reachable at a hostname identical to the alias, or the service name if no alias was specified.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Can you explain how to solve this problem? The answered question doesn't give a normal explanation on how to deal with the problem!